# ¿ Cómo hacer este tipo de slide(cardview) en android studio?

Tags: android-studio, slide, cardview

Estoy intentando hacer un slide en horizontal a partir de un `ViewPager` tal como hice hace unos dias un `VerticalViewPager` donde arrastrando con el dedo podías ver una imagen pero únicamente podías ver 1 por pantalla y para ver la siguiente tenías que arrastrar y perdías la que estabas viendo.

Todo esto a partir de la creación de:

`private List<Fragment> fragmentList;` para la creación de la lista
y `pagerAdapter = new VPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),list);` para el `pagerAdapter` necesario en este `Slide`.

El problema es que esto ya no me sirve y no consigo realizar ni me sale lo que necesito, no hay forma, y me refiero a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Donde tenga una imagen en pequeño a la izquierda que es la anterior** y una **imagen en pequeño a la derecha que es la siguiente**.

**Conforme vaya arrastrando, la foto que se situe en el medio será más grande que las otras de su lado, creando un slide muy dinámico**. Vi algo similar hace años donde existía inncluso una animación cuando ibas pasando fotos muy llamativo.

Gracias de antemano.